# Oracle 11g Express Edition

Tags: oracle

I have been tasked with installing the latest oracle XE edition.  The versions I have installed recently are all 11g, but when I look for the XE edition I only see 10g.

- Is 10g the latest XE edition or Oracle?
- If that is the case, does anyone know why is there not an 11g express edition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XE is free while Oracle is not. Could be the reason why they do not put much focus on it. This article says that it won't be out at least until when the first patch of 11g R2 is released.

http://news.techworld.com/applications/3203909/oracle-stalls-over-11g-express-release/